# insert record in android studio (kotlin) using postgresql

Tags: android, postgresql, kotlin

Is there any documentation on how to insert or retrieve data from PostgreSQL to the android studio, I am using `kotlin`. and I am new in Android Studio. I already have this code in my **MainActivity.kt** and **connectiondb.java**

connectiondb.java

```
public class connectionDb {
    Connection connection=null;
    public Connection ConnectionDb(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mytransactiondb", "postgres", "root");

        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.err.println(err.getMessage());
        }

        return connection;
    }
    protected void close_connection(Connection con)throws Exception{
        con.close();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btn_login.setOnClickListener{
            val objConnectionDb=connectionDb()
            objConnectionDb.connection

            Log.i("connectinDb()", "Connected")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try `connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://10.0.2.2:5432/mytransactiondb", "postgres", "root");
PreparedStatement st = c.prepareStatement("your query "); // create and then setup prepareStatement
// then execute your statment`

Comment: How do i connect it to my postgresql?

Comment: how you tried the above code with an emulator?

Comment: Will this help ?  https://www.pgcon.org/2011/schedule/attachments/194_pgcon2011-pgdroid.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough I have not worked on PostreSQL with Android, got this documentation which says.

Below is the approach to insert query using PostreSQL for Android

```
PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement(”INSERT INTO films (title) ”+”VALUES(?) ;”);
st.setString(1,”On Stranger Tides”);
int rows=st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

Go through [this link](https://www.pgcon.org/2011/schedule/attachments/194_pgcon2011-pgdroid.pdf) for more details.

More insights over [here](https://www.pgcon.org/2011/schedule/track/Applications/278.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for documentation:

This is [KotliQuery](https://www.kotlinresources.com/library/kotliquery/), very useful and simple to use.
For example, to execute an `insert` statement, you can do it with:

```
val insertQuery: String = "insert into members (name,  created_at) values (?, ?)"
session.run(queryOf(insertQuery, "Alice", Date()).asUpdate)
```

Comment: how do i connect it to my postgresql?